# Center Screen JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser, jinternalframe

I want to set the location of my `JFileChooser` at the center of my `JInternalFrame`:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
fileChooser.setLocation();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your `JFileChooser` in every Component.

```
// Your JInternal Frame
JInternalFrame inFrame = new JInternalFrame("", true, true, true, true);

// Your JFileChooser
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));

// put filechooser in internal frame
inFrame.add(fileChooser);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but this is more effective fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

Answer (score 0):

```
fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".